# AsyncTask: ввод данных и вывод по мере готовности

Tags: android, java

Вопрос ученика. Осваиваю `AsyncTask`, передаю в задачу `String` url`ы, хочется обрабатывать их в задаче по очереди и по мере готовности выводить`string`ответ от каждого url в свой`textViev`.
Передавать в задачу научился и получать результат тоже.
Вот, понимаю, что в задаче надо в цикле обработать полученные ссылки, но не знаю как.
И самое главное как потом вывести результат по мере готовности?

Answer (score 1):

У `AsyncTask`  есть специальный метод для вывода промежуточных результатов `onProgressUpdate()`.

В `doInBackground` в цикле обрабатываете данные и вызывайте `onProgressUpdate()` потом. Что-то вроде:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

  ...
  for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        count = parser.getValue(e, KEY_COUNT);
        publishProgress(у);
  }
  ...
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Element... e) {
  super.onProgressUpdate(values);
  // что-то делаем
}
```

`onProgressUpdate()` как и `onPostExecute` имеет доступ к GUI

Comment: Вы наверное хотели сказать не doInBackground а onPostExecute?
насколько знаю doInBackground не имеет доступа к UI

Comment: @Sedek да, перепутал )

Answer (score -2):

Просто сделай отдельно 4 разных AsyncTask изменив следующим образом:

Добавь конструктор:

```
private TextView mTextView;

public MyTask(TextView view) {
     mTextView = view;
}
```

Потом в onPostExecute():

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     mTextView.setText(result);
}
```

Потом вызови их таким образом (ну или как тебе удобней):

```
new MyTask(text_view).execute(url);
```

Update:
В соответствии с пожеланиями автора темы, чтоб TextView обновлялись из одного AsyncTask:

1. Привязать TextView к URL, например так - HashMap<String, TextView>
2. После окончания обработки определенного URL отправить сам URL (он ключ) и результат обработки в publishProgress()
3. В onProgressUpdate() соответственно подхватить URL и результат обработки, при помощи URL выгрузить из Map необходимый TextView и вставить в него результат.

И на будущее:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html
http://startandroid.ru/en/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/149-urok-86-asynctask-znakomstvo-neslozhnyj-primer.html

Comment: А почему так проще?

Comment: Как я понимаю, тебе нужно обработать каждую ссылку и результат обработки каждой вывести в свой TextView? Как я написал, получается, что ты на каждый TextView создаешь AsyncTask, который, параллельно с другими, обрабатывает ссылки выводит результат в свой TextView.

Comment: Я уже делал 4 разных, но при этом они одновременно запускаются если процессор позволяет? А мне хотелось бы, что бы ссылки по очереди обрабатывались. А если ссылок 10-15 и под каждую запускать поток? А кроме этих ссылок ещё есть потоки с другими задачами.

Comment: Андроид не запустит одновременно слишком много потоков на параллельную обработку. Полно приложений где запускается целый GridView большущий, где каждая картинка подгружается из интернета. Там одновременно запускается и по 30 AsyncTask и ничего не тормозит.

Comment: Всё равно мне кажется это не правильным. Мне не нужно выполнение всех одновременно, тем более эти данные не критичны и пользователь их увидит не сразу.
Мне осталось только понять как в цикле обработать ссылки и по каждой получить ответ от xmlParser в publishProgress()
а так вроде бы решено.

Comment: Обновил. Если возникнут проблемы с написанием кода, проверь ссылки.